# cmake DEFINED does not seems to recognize variable

Tags: cmake

I have this code in cmake:

```
#mandatory
SET(BOOST_DIR "$ENV{BOOST_HOME}")
if (DEFINED ${BOOST_DIR})
    #global include directories
    include_directories(${BOOST_DIR})
else(DEFINED ${BOOST_DIR})
    message( STATUS "BOOST_HOME at ${BOOST_DIR}")

    message( FATAL_ERROR "Undefined BOOST_HOME env var.")
endif(DEFINED ${BOOST_DIR})
```

The env var BOOST_HOME is defined (/home/ferran/boost). The behavior is very odd because the output is:

```
-- BOOST_HOME at /home/ferran/boost
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (message):
  Undefined BOOST_HOME env var.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

So, the var exists and prints its contents and at the same time does not exists?

Comment: How did you set `$ENV{BOOST_HOME}`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to avoid dereferencing the variable `BOOST_DIR` in the `if` statement:

```
set(BOOST_DIR "$ENV{BOOST_HOME}")
if(BOOST_DIR)               # <--- Use 'BOOST_DIR', not 'DEFINED ${BOOST_DIR}'
    #global include directories
    include_directories(${BOOST_DIR})
else()
    message(STATUS "BOOST_HOME at ${BOOST_DIR}")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Undefined BOOST_HOME env var.")
endif()
```

By dereferencing `BOOST_DIR`, you're effectively querying if CMake has a variable called `/home/ferran/boost` defined.

Comment: It doesn't work. It seems that in case "$ENV{BOOST_HOME}" is not defined, BOOST_DIR is set to empty, but defined. I've solved by using "if (DEFINED ENV{BOOST_HOME})"

Comment: Yes - sorry.  It's because `"$ENV{BOOST_HOME}"` has the quotation marks.  If those weren't there and `$ENV{BOOST_HOME}` wasn't defined, then `BOOST_DIR` also wouldn't be defined.  However, the quotation marks are necessary in case the value of `BOOST_HOME` includes a space.  I've updated the answer with a slightly different fix to yours.  Either should be fine.